# Two custom elements via directives, only one is rendered on the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives that define two elements I want to use on my page. If I use both directives on the page only the first one is rendered. I'm sure I'm breaking some rule of angular, not sure what though.

Directives:

```
  //The template and handler for the set username button
  chatApp.directive('setUsernameButton', ['username', function(username){
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('click', function(){
        username.setUsername();
        scope.$parent.$apply();
      });
    };
    var template = '<div ng-disabled="username.invalidUsername" ng-class="{disabled: username.invalidUsername}" id="setNameButton" class="ui teal button">Set Name</div>'
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: template,
      link: link,
      scope: false
    };
  }]);

  //The template and handler for username input field
  chatApp.directive('usernameInputField', ['username', function(username){
    function link(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
          username.setUsername();
          scope.$parent.$apply();
        }
      });
    };
    var template = '\
      <div class="ui input">\
        <input ng-model="username.name" type="text" placeholder="Username...">\
      </div>'
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: template,
      link: link,
      scope: false
    };
  }]);
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div ng-if="!username.nameSet" class="ten wide column">
  <set-username-button />                        
  <username-input-field />                       
</div>
```

Comment: could you please provide a sample demo in jsfiddle

Comment: @adib.mosharrof Can I not use angular in JSFiddle? I can't seem to get it to bind to my module in a very simple way. `var chatApp = angular.module("chatApp", []);` `<div ng-app="chatApp"></div>` angular just throws the `[$injector:nomod] Module 'chatApp' is not available!` error.

Comment: yes, even i saw that.. try using codepen..
you are injecting 'username' into your directives, but there is not service with username.

Comment: The service is not listed here. It exists, and functions as expected, this issue no longer occurs if I use divs with the attributes named after their appropriate directives. It only seems to happen when trying to use custom element types. If I switch their order in the HTML, only the first is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the directive as an attribute, both the directives show up properly. If you want to use it as an element, it will work if you wrap your directive elements inside a div. Both ways work. Use it however you like

[demo](http://codepen.io/adibM/pen/LNqyvq)

```
<div set-username-button></div>
<div username-input-field></div>
```

or you could do this

```
  <div>
      <set-username-button />
  </div>
  <div>
    <username-input-field /> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah, they need to be wrapped in divs, is there  a spot in the documentation that mentions this?

Comment: normally i use directives as attributes.. I didnt find this after briefly scheming through, so need to dig through the docs to see if this problem is mentioned..